# using jquery remove part of a cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-clone

having a difficult time removing a div inside of a cloned element. run the snippet and notice the do not clone me part gets appended even though it is removed.

```js
let myhtml = `<div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="mycontainer">
                clone me
                <div class="noClone">
                 do not clone me
                </div>
                <button class="clonebtn"> clone it </button>
             </div>`

$(document).ready(function() {
  let content = $(myhtml);
  $('.row').append(content);

  $('.row').on('click', '.clonebtn', function() {
    let container = $(this).closest('.mycontainer');
    let clonedContainer = container.clone();
    clonedContainer.remove('.noClone');
    $('.row').append(clonedContainer);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  </div>
</div>
```

or run the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/k6jz9xe2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let myhtml = `<div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="mycontainer">
                clone me
                <div class="noClone">
                 do not clone me
                </div>
                <button class="clonebtn"> clone it </button>
             </div>`

$(document).ready(function() {
  let content = $(myhtml);
  $('.row').append(content);

  $('.row').on('click', '.clonebtn', function() {
    let container = $(this).closest('.mycontainer');
    let clonedContainer = container.clone();
    clonedContainer.find('.noClone').remove();
    $('.row').append(clonedContainer);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not just post code as your answer. What was wrong and what have you fixed?

Comment: I copied `".noClone"` inside find() function since we don't know where is element, it could be first child or child of  child so I just added find() with wanted selector :D

Comment: According to the documentation, you can put a parameter in `remove()`

Comment: I seen it and removed from comment, but it does not worked like any time for me :D Thats why I was so hyped to know this :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all elements inside the parent div with a class of `noClone` to remove.

`$(selector).remove(anotherselector)` in jQuery only removes any elements matching `anotherselector` from the Array returned by `selector`. The selector given to the `remove()` function is only applied to the elements contained in the jQuery collection not to the children of those elements. It is analogous to `$(selector).filter(anotherselector).remove()`.

Consider the following HTML and jQuery code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
Foo 
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
</div>
<script>
$('#foo').remove('#bar');
</script>
```

You may expect that the div with the `id` "bar" inside the div with the `id` "foo" will be removed, but this is not the case. Why? The `$('#foo')` selector returns an Array with just one item: the `div` with the `id` of "foo". jQuery attempts to `filter` through the Array and find an element matching the `$('#bar')` selector. No element is found and nothing will happen.

The following selector, however, will remove the div with the `id` of "bar".

```
$('div').remove('#bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
Foo 
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
</div>
<script>
$('div').remove('#bar');
</script>
```

The `$('div')` selector returns an Array with all the `div`s on the page. jQuery filters through all of the `div`s to find an `div` matching the `$('#bar')` selector (having an `id` of "bar"). Having found one, it removes it.

```js
let myhtml = `<div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="mycontainer">
                clone me
                <div class="noClone">
                 do not clone me
                </div>
                <button class="clonebtn"> clone it </button>
             </div>`;

$(document).ready(function() {
  let content = $(myhtml);
  $('.row').append(content);

  $('.row').on('click', '.clonebtn', function() {
    let container = $(this).closest('.mycontainer');
    let clonedContainer = container.clone();
    clonedContainer.find('.noClone').remove();
    $('.row').append(clonedContainer);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me take this one i am learner I just got hyped to know this :D

Comment: According to https://api.jquery.com/remove/ you can pass a selector as a parameter.

Comment: @lee Taylor  I also read that in documentation so unsure why my original post is not working without the .find()

Comment: @LeeTaylor See my edited answer for the explanation.

Comment: @BryanDellinger See my edited answer for the explanation.